# R: pass a list of filtering conditions into a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like:

```
   Symbol Yield    PE    Growth  
1    ABBV  3.46 18.80      5.00  
2     ABM  2.24 21.18      3.33  
3     ABT  2.26 23.65     10.85  
4     ADM  1.91 22.29      9.08  
5     ADP  2.46 25.83      8.57  
6     AFL  2.25  9.26      5.97  
7     ALB  1.44 13.53     13.15  
8    ANDE  1.02 19.59      5.74  
9     AOS  1.29 25.11      9.99  
10    APD  2.41 25.08      2.53  
11   ARLP  5.50 11.69      1.99  
12   AROW  3.83 14.68      1.01  
13  ARTNA  3.67 23.91      3.20  
14   ATNI  1.68  3.14      7.50  
15    ATO  2.97 18.59      1.72
```

and a long list of boolean filtering conditions like

```
conditions = c('Symbol in `ABM', 'Growth > 1.2', 'Yield within (2 3)', 'PE>3',....)
```

Is there a way using base R or dplyr that I can do something like

```
for (condition in conditions) {    
cond = expression(condition)
    dataframe = dataframe[which(cond),]}
```

so that I can continually add to the condition list, instead of manually pasting them and using multiple &'s in the index?

The output should be

```
filter(dataframe, Symbol in 'ABM' & Growth > 1.2 & Yield within (2 3) & PE>3 &...)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Should the conditions be evaluated one by one or all together?

Comment: I am trying to do them all together (multiple and.)

Comment: `conditions = c('Symbol %in% "ABM"', 'Growth > 1.2', 'Yield %in% c(2,3)', 'PE>3')` is probably closer to what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R version:

```
conditions <- with(dat, list(Symbol %in% "ABM", Growth > 1.2, Yield > 2, Yield < 3, PE > 3))
dat[Reduce(`&`, conditions ),]
#  Symbol Yield    PE Growth
#2    ABM  2.24 21.18   3.33
```

Comment: I was hoping for a python-type reduce solution! I didn't realize R had its own version.

Comment: @michel - see the functional programming help page via `?Reduce` for a lot of the similar tools like `Reduce` `Map` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

conditions = c('Symbol %in% "ABM"', 'Growth > 1.2', 'Yield > 2', 'Yield < 3', 'PE > 3')

df %>% filter_(conditions)


  Symbol Yield    PE Growth
1    ABM  2.24 21.18   3.33
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(Symbol = structure(1:15, .Label = c("ABBV", "ABM", 
"ABT", "ADM", "ADP", "AFL", "ALB", "ANDE", "AOS", "APD", "ARLP", 
"AROW", "ARTNA", "ATNI", "ATO"), class = "factor"), Yield = c(3.46, 
2.24, 2.26, 1.91, 2.46, 2.25, 1.44, 1.02, 1.29, 2.41, 5.5, 3.83, 
3.67, 1.68, 2.97), PE = c(18.8, 21.18, 23.65, 22.29, 25.83, 9.26, 
13.53, 19.59, 25.11, 25.08, 11.69, 14.68, 23.91, 3.14, 18.59), 
    Growth = c(5, 3.33, 10.85, 9.08, 8.57, 5.97, 13.15, 5.74, 
    9.99, 2.53, 1.99, 1.01, 3.2, 7.5, 1.72)), .Names = c("Symbol", 
"Yield", "PE", "Growth"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Comment: Now do it by referencing `conditions` and not typing it in manually. That's the tricky part.

Comment: Yep... that solves it I think. Not sure how to do it in base R though. Probably some ugly `eval(parse(...))` nonsense, which would pain me to use.

Comment: filter_ is deprecated. Is there an alternative solution?