# R: find row by two values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to find in a table a row which matches two column values.
I know that I can use which function:

```
my_data[which(my_data$col1 == "val"),]
```

But how do I do this for 2 or more values?
I've already tried && operator in any order, still doesn't help.

Comment: `&` works well with vectors, `&&` doesn't. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558921/4996248

Comment: Essentially this is a join operation too - `merge(mtcars, list(cyl=6, gear=4))` for instance.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493031/r-pass-a-list-of-filtering-conditions-into-a-dataframe/38493329 too.

Comment: Igor, did you end up solving your problem?

Comment: @lebelinoz I will write results next days, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_data[which(my_data$col1 == "val" & my_data$col2 == "val2"),]` ought to work in base R.

Comment: this actually works. It's strange, but it was not working because I had one column named with my_data$T , somehow "T" is glitching

Answer (score 5):

Using the `filter` function in `dplyr` you can do this without too much trouble. Try something like this:

```
my_data %>%
  filter(col1 == "val", col2 == "other")
```

By default, you have two or more statements, `filter` treats it as an AND, but you can be more explicit `&` like so

```
my_data %>%
  filter(col1 == "val" & col2 == "other")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subset` in `base R`:

```
subset(my_data, col1 == "val" & col2 == "char")
```