# how to pass conditions in the form of dataframe into dplyr::filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of conditions like:

```
cond = data.frame(cyl=4, vs=0, am=1)
```

I want to pass the conditions to filter my data.

```
mtcars %in% filter (???)
```

Is there any way to do that? I want the solution to be programable, so that I can pass a list of conditions in the form of dataframe(or list) to any dataset.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `cond = data.frame(cyl=4, vs=0, am=1)` That's not really a list of conditions, how would you implement less that or greater than in this case?

Comment: how can I convert it to a list of conditions with programming? @Jack Brookes

Comment: One option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493031/r-pass-a-list-of-filtering-conditions-into-a-dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your conditions are always "equals" (i.e. you want `cyl == 4`, `vs==0` etc.) and are always "anded" together, then you can just use `inner_join` on the data.

```
mtcars_filtered <- inner_join(mtcars, cond)
```

This also has the advantage that you can create more complex joins by adding appropriate rows to the `cond` table.

If you want subtler conditions, you will need to get into non-standard evaluation. This will make your eyes fall out of your head. Good luck!

Comment: yes. my condition always comes from dataframe. This is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although, the answer has already been accepted, but here is my attempt.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
    filter(eval(parse(text = paste0(names(cond), "  ==  ",unname(cond), collapse = " & "))))
```

**Output**:

```
  mpg cyl  disp hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
1  26   4 120.3 91 4.43 2.14 16.7  0  1    5    2
```